# Nunit pass params to Test from nunit-console

Tags: console, nunit, runner

I am using below to pass a single parameter to my Test.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\>"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit-console" "D:\Automation\ClassLibrary2\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary2.dll /run:ClassLibrary2.Class1.Test1(\"option1\")
```

MyCode:

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1(string browser)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Browse );
        }

    }
}
```

Result:
Tests run: 0, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0 seconds

So how to Pass parameters directly from nunit-console to Test.

Comment: is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The way that I have normally solved the problem is by allowing environment variables to override configuration properties.

Then I can control the environment variables from build scripts, build servers, etc. to control that the tests run in the environment that I want them to.

For example:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DataAccessTest
{
    static string GetConnectionString() {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStringForTest") ?? DefaultConnectionString;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test() {
        var context = new DataContext(GetConnectionString());
        ...
    }
}
```